# Como guardar a sessão do usuário em um site armazenado na AWS - S3?

Tags: javascript, session, amazon-aws

Na AWS podemos usar o serviço S3 para disponibilizar web sites estáticos. Seundo a [documentação](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) entende-se por estático a não utilização de back-end como php, asp.net, etc.

Porém posso carregar conteúdo dinamicamente através de requisições javascript get, consumindo end-points de APIs que podem ser carrgadas assincronamente. POsso carregar imagens, graficos, videos textos e etc.

O unico problema que estou encontrando é como guardar a sessão do usuário.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Então cara, vou responder por aqui porque não posso comentar.
Você não vai conseguir armazenar sessão através de API (requisições ajax, etc). Isso porque essas requisições são completamente independentes umas das outras e geralmente o backend trata cada uma delas como sessões independentes.
Existem algumas formas de você contornar isso. O que eu costumo fazer é utilizar um [JWT (Json Web Token)](https://jwt.io/). Com ele você consegue armazenar informações sobre o usuário dentro do mesmo e recuperar elas dentro do seu backend. Estes tokens são muitas vezes utilizados em forma de sessão, você pode enviar uma data de expiração dentro dele e renovar essa expiração a cada chamada ao backend, por exemplo, fazendo com que, caso o usuário fique mais de 20min sem chamar o backend, o token se torne inválido e ele precise logar novamente. Você pode armazenar esse token no sessionStorage, localStorage ou até mesmo utilizar cookies.

Através do S3, pelo fato de ser estático, você não irá conseguir trabalhar com sessões, já que sessões geralmente funcionam bem em sites que são renderizados pelo proprio backend (Django, Pyramid, entre outros frameworks) fazem isso, mas, você não conseguirá usar o S3 para publicar este tipo de site.

Resumindo, eu sugiro você utilizar o JWT para trabalhar com sessões (simular elas, no caso)